# How to instantiate a generic T in a method in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

`FileInformation` is a class with a string property `path`. I am trying to pass it as a type in a method `getValue<T>()` and then obtain my property from the returned object. My issue here is that the function doesn't know what is `T` and therefore I can't instantiate it. is there a way to create a new instance of `T` based on the caller method?

**Caller,**

```
This.getValue<FileInformation>().subscribe((value) => {
 console.log(v.data); // object is returned
 console.log(v.data.path); // always undefined
})
```

**Method,**

```
private value: Subject<ISignalRHub<any>> = new Subject<ISignalRHub<any>>();


    public getValue<T>() {
              this.value = new Subject<SignalRHub<T>>();
              this.hubConnection.on(CRUD.create, (data: T) => {
              this.value.next({ method: CRUD.update, data: data });
         });

        const val = new Subject<ISignalRHub<T>>();
        this.value.subscribe((v: ISignalRHub<T>) => {
          val.next(v);
        });
        return val.asObservable();
      }
```

**Update**

This is an output of the value and the nested objects

```
 console.log(v);
 console.log(v.data);
 console.log(v.data.path);
```

[image]

**Update**

Based on the comments below, my issue here was the JSON resolver that was serializing all properties in Pascal case. Thanks to @Antoniossss for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This.getValue<FileInformation>().subscribe((value) => {
 console.log(v.data); // object is returned
 console.log(v.data.path); // always undefined
})
```

Well, value here will NEVER be of type `FileInformation` and it will always plain JS Object. Type used here is only for usage control (to detect access to non existing properties). This works quite well with interfaces - as object may match interface signature. For class instances, you have to crete those yourself

```
    This.getValue()
    .pipe(
       map(jsonData=>new FileInformation(jsonData)
     ).subscribe((value:FileInformation) => // here value will be indeed a FileInformation instance
    })
```

Obviously you have to create `constructor` for this example to work, that will map json into your `FileInformation`.

Comment: I tried first with interface and I had the same outcome

Comment: double check if `value` is what you expect it to be. If you had problems with interface, then it would work just like that, which means that `value` is not what you thinks it is.

Comment: This is what drove me crazy in the first place, see `v.data` is outputted properly and I can see the nested object value in my console. if I try to get the nested value I get `undefined`. so I switched from an `interface` to a `class` thinking that I need to re-instantiate first.

Comment: *see v.data is outputted properly* no I dont see as its not in question. Also i dont know what `FileInformation` as you didnt include that neither.

Comment: so to make my post brief I did not include all properties but I started the question by stating that `FileInformation` has a property called `path`

Comment: how about `Path` ?

Comment: for some reason my the C# class does not have the correct JSON serialization. Thanks that was my problem

Comment: I am using SignalR hubs and I was using a different JSON resolver which serialized all properties in Pascal case